# Compute sha256 ignoring metadata - Javascript

Tags: javascript, hash, metadata

I want to keep track of modifications of any type of files, and I'm using Javascript and the **SHA256 cryptographic** hash function.

The problem is that for some type of files, even if there are no actual changes to the document, the hash changes (I'm assuming it's because of metadata changes).

For instance, an empty word document in format docx gives, say

```
 hash = 1bcf93...
```

If the user opens the document and closes it, the hash changes, and I don't want that.

Is there a way to compute the hash ignoring metadata for all files?

I am parsing files with 'fs' and computing the hash with '`js-sha256`', i.e. `FileReader.ReadAsBinaryString()` and then `sha256()`.

Comment: Are you able to remove the header from the file? That's probably where the metadata is stored, including things like 'Date last opened'. If you can trim that from the file, then I think the hash should stay the same.

Comment: That would be nice, do you know how to do that parsing from javascript?

Comment: I've checked the `FileReader` API's, and to be honest, I have no idea.. The problem is that you want it for *any* type of file, so a parser would be very hard I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a cryptographic hash will produce a different hash if any single byte has a different value, no matter how irrelevant that byte it. That's the whole point of a hash.

Depending on your exact requirements, it may or may not be able to get close enough.

If your requirements are "does this content look similar enough to be considered equal" with pretty lax requirements of legality then you can try to produce a somewhat stable text representation of all your inputs and hash that instead (for example extract the pure text of your doc file and discarding all formatting and metadata).

If you need anything more subtle than that (e.g. "does this document have any *user-visible* changes) then it will become incredibly hard to define precisely which parts need to be hashed and which shouldn't be, which means you **will** get it wrong which might be terrible (or maybe errors are not a huge deal in your requirements?)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please assume that I know what a cryptographic function is and that I know what I am doing. I am actually familiar with the very construction of SHA256. As the title states, all I want to do is ignore metadata and parse only (binary) content. You suggest to extract pure text from doc file discarding metadata, would you know how to actually do it in Javascript? Thanks again

Comment: I assure you that whatever you are doing is already only considering "binary data". The "meta data" that's causing you problems is inherent to the word file format and not something external to the file. So to "ignore" it you'd have to have deep understanding of the word file format in your code and a very precise definition of what exactly "metadata" is in this case (which is tricky). I don't know if there's file format libraries for the word format for JavaScript, but I wouldn't be surprised if there were.

Comment: I see, so I would need to study all different formats and their encodings. In my case, I define a change only as user inflicted intentionally, but what bothers me most is the case of re-saving the document or changing spelling. As a comment above states, this info should be in the header (it would be somewhat invasive if it wasn't), so my best shot is to try and remove the header from the binary data. Would you agree?

Comment: @Tal-Botvinnik: that depends on what your actual use case is. If "close enough" is good enough for you, then that's a perfectly reasonable approach and the tricky bit is just to define how far the "header" goes, but that should be doable. But if you need the hash to be different for every document that looks different from another, then it's not good enough, because in theory a script could check for a value in the header and modify the content of the document depending on the value then two "identical" documents with different "headers" could look different. That's why I asked for the goal.

Comment: My actual use case is to store the hash value of documents in order to prove authenticity later. One a hash is stored in some safe box, the file might still be accessible, might be sent by mail, or resaved by some user (out of reflex).

Comment: @Tal-Botvinnik: if it's about proving authenticity, then I personally wouldn't think that skipping the "header" is a reasonable trade-off. Yes, it would make the system slightly less convenient (if one accidentally modifies the file), but implementing that feature would make attacks possible that could easily have been avoided otherwise.

Comment: [OfficeProps](https://github.com/TorkelV/officeprops) can remove metadata from office files.